# What is the process to create this style of text warp?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-creative-cloud

Looking to recreate this style of warped text. I've tried the warp text styles that are available; arc, arc lower/upper but not able to get near this desired style. Would love some pointers/guide on this. Thank you!

[image: Warped text example]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to [curve text in Photoshop](https://medialoot.com/blog/three-ways-to-curve-text-in-photoshop/).

- Select the Text tool (T) and type your text.
- With the text layer selected and the Text tool (T) active, click on the “Create warped text” icon in the toolbar.
- In the Warp Text window, select the "Arc Lower"-style.

[image]

You can use [WhatFontIsThis](https://www.whatfontis.com/) or [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) to get somewhat similar fonts.

Comment: I was able to walk through the instructions and get the desired effect from the link you provided. Thank you!